# Linux audio capture in c++

Tags: c++, linux, audio

I am starting a project to write a c++ application in Linux which can localize the direction of a sound based on input from 4 different mics.

I will be needing an API that let's me capture audio from multiple soundcards and would allow me access to each sample taken represented in a byte format.

Could someone please point me in the right direction as to what Linux c++ library can help me achieve this. This library should simply allow me to continuously read samples from multiple mics at set intervals which would yield some kind of output byte[] that I can then input into my sound localization algorithm.

Comment: If Qt is not a "too big" dependency for your application, you could look into [Qt's multimedia library](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/audiooverview.html#low-level-audio-playback-and-recording), specifically the [`QAudioInput`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qaudioinput.html) class. I personally didn't use it yet, but it seems to support multiple sound cards and you get a raw byte stream in some PCM format. It sounds like a perfect fit for your needs. As a bonus it would be platform independent.

Comment: That being said, such questions are off-topic for this site...

Answer (score 0):

[ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page) is the grand-daddy of all audio APIs. It provides an API and command line tools for audio capture, and is present in pretty much every Linux distribution.